# Permutations avoiding a family of consecutive patterns

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, asymptotics, enumerative-combinatorics, pattern-avoidance

Let $B=\{1324,14325,154326,1654327,\ldots\}$ be the set of permutation patterns of the form $1(m-1)(m-2)\cdots 2m$ for $m\geq 4$. I'm interested in the set $\mathcal P$ of permutations that avoid all of the patterns in $B$ *consecutively*. That is, a permutation is in $\mathcal P$ if it does not have any consecutive subsequences that are order-isomorphic to patterns from $B$. I'm wondering if anyone has looked at these permutations or if anything is known about their asymptotics. I can see on the OEIS that the asymptotics for permutations consecutively avoiding $1324$ are known. This gives me a quick upper bound on the asymptotics for $\mathcal P$, but I was hoping for something a little more precise.

The family $\mathcal P$ arises in a paper that I am writing that is not really about pattern avoidance. I don't really want to devote a lot of space in the paper to proving results about $\mathcal P$ since that would detract from the focus of the article. So I was hoping there might be some result that I could black-box.

Comment: what is the OEIS sequence? and what type of bound would you hope to get?

Comment: The OEIS sequence for permutations consecutively avoiding 1324 is A113228. The asymptotics for those are $c\cdot d^n\cdot n!$, where $c\approx 1.15104$ and $d\approx 0.95585$. I guess I'd hope for any exponential improvement (an improvement upon $d$).

Comment: I get initial terms `1, 1, 2, 6, 23, 109, 619, 4094, 30920, 262673, 2479256, 25739699, 291520932`. Assuming those are correct, it's not in OEIS, and I get no Google hits for `"291520932" permutations`.